# Use the app selection interface to choose different ways to launch activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like to use the app selection interface to change starting values in an activity. The app selection interface I'm referring to is the one that pops up when you have multiple apps to catch the same type of intent, and allows the user to choose one as well as always use that selection.

The activity in question currently displays a button for the selection of two choices, builds an intent based on that, fires the intent, and exits. That's it. Instead of the custom built button, I'd like to use the above stated interface to display the choices, as the majority of the interface will retain the user's chosen language. Ideally, this would be used to just set a value in the Activity's class. The two selections would need to have different names, in this case term/xterm.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
    final Intent intent = getLaunchIntent();

    //Would like to replace this Alert Dialog with the app selection interface
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.launch_preference);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.term_preference, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            intent.putExtra("launchType", "launchTerm");
            dialog.dismiss();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.xterm_preference, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            intent.putExtra("launchType", "launchXTerm");
            dialog.dismiss();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
    builder.create().dismiss();
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: I mean, sure. None of the code is really relevant to the question though. I'm asking whether something is possible and how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in this by doing the following:

If the intent that creates my main activity comes from being launched, I send a custom intent that is caught by two other activities in the app. This allows for a selection between the two. The text that is displayed can be set by putting an `android:label` element in the opening `intent-filter`.

Each of those activities then sends an intent to the main activity with an extra determining launch type, and execution can continue as normal.

```
    <activity android:name=".Activity1" >
        <intent-filter android:label="text to be displayed in selection" >
            <action android:name="SELECTION_INTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activity2" >
        <intent-filter android:label="text to be displayed in selection" >
            <action android:name="SELECTION_INTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="CHOICE_INTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning : Partial answer (look at the bottom)**

The app selection interface you refereing to is showing when there are several ways to react to an intent.
So I guess your application should declare 2 different definitions for the same intent.

The idea is to create 2 activities for this (let's call them "ReactActivity1" and "ReactActivity2"), which will launch your third activity with different parameters

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".ReactActivity1" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="(insert a scheme here)" />
            (...)
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ReactActivity2" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="(insert a scheme here)" />
            (...)
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**ReactActivity1**

```
(...)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent intent = getLaunchIntent();
    intent.putExtra("launchType", "launchTerm");
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // Running finish() inside onCreate() method will make this activity 
              // "invisible" (it will never be shown to the user, and will
              // immediatly be replaced by the next one...)
}
```

**ReactActivity2**

```
(...)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent intent = getLaunchIntent();
    intent.putExtra("launchType", "launchXTerm");
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

**Issue :** The problem is that I'm not sure it is possible to make both choice look different (with a different name, like "Term"/"XTerm"). I think that Android system will show the name of the application in both case.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there would necessarily need to be a way to change the naming of the two options. Thanks though, this is still useful information.

Comment: Maybe there's one way to do it. I just don't know it, and didn't looked for one in the docs. Maybe some additional search/try work is required here.